# No se inserta los datos con PDO a Mysql Ayuda

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tengo un problema al insertar datos a MySQL con xammp usando la sintaxis PDO de php al enviar el formulario no me arroja ningún error pero tampoco se guarda los datos me devuelve datos no enviado ayuda no se que pasa ya hecho de todo...

La base de datos esta bien y no se que pasa.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

### **Haca es el registro**

He intentado traer la base de datos en el registro pensando que tal ves era un error de acceso o algo a si, pero tampoco es lo mismo .

```
<?php
  
include_once "../Database/database.php";
$conexion = new Base_datos();


if(isset($_POST["enviarR"])){

  if( !$_POST["email"]=="" && !$_POST["nombre"]=="" && !$_POST["apellidos"]=="" && !$_POST["contraseña"]=="" && !$_POST["fecha"]=="" && !$_POST["pais"]==""){


    $email= $_POST["email"];
    $nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellidos= $_POST["apellidos"];
    $contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];
    $fecha=  $_POST["fecha"];
    $pais=$_POST["pais"];



    $sql="INSERT INTO 'registro_usuario' ('Email','Nombre','Apellido','Password','Fecha','País') VALUES (':email',':nombre',':apellidos',':contraseña',':fecha',':pais')";
    $valor= $conexion->Conectar()->prepare($sql);
    $cifra_contra = password_hash($contraseña,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    

    
if($valor->execute([':email'=>$email, ':nombre'=>$nombre, ':apellidos'=>$apellidos, ':contraseña'=>$contraseña, ':fecha'=>$fecha,':pais'=>$pais])){

echo "Datos enviados";


}else{

  echo "Datos no enviados";
}



  }else{

?>

<style>

  .alerta{

      display:inline;

          }       
</style>

<?php

  }
}




?>
```

**Esta en la conexión a la base de datos**

---

```
class  Base_datos{


private $servidor;
private $base_datos;
private $usuario;
private $contraseña;




 function __construct(){


$this-> servidor="localhost";
$this-> base_datos= "usuarios";
$this-> usuario= "root";
$this-> contraseña= "";


}





function Conectar(){

try {
    
$sqlConetion="mysql:host=".$this->servidor ;";dbname=".$this->base_datos;
$pdo= new PDO($sqlConetion,$this->usuario,$this->contraseña);
echo "Conectado";
return $pdo;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    
    echo "Error".$e->getMessage();


}


}}
```

Comment: Por favor cambia las imágenes por el texto del código pulsando en [edit], es imposible analizar el problema con las capturas de pantalla que muestras. Gracias.

Comment: Listo amigo ya esta.

Comment: Empezamos corrigiendo la consulta: `$sql="INSERT INTO registro_usuario (Email,Nombre,Apellido,Password,Fecha,País) VALUES (:email,:nombre,:apellidos,:contraseña,:fecha,:pais)";` todas esas comillas simples sobran. También, la `ñ` pude provocar errores si no tienes bien configurada la codificación en el entorno. Conviene evitar `ñ`, acentos, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código debería prever todos los posibles escenarios de error y controlarlos. Pero no lo estás haciendo. La consulta puede fallar al prepararla (no conexión, error de sintaxis)  o al ejecutarla (error de clave duplicada u otros).

Tu consulta SQL es incorrecta. En las consultas preparadas no debes poner los marcadores rodeados de comillas. Y el identificador para columnas es el conocido como *backtick*, la comilla simple invertida: `

También, se supone que deberías guardar la contraseña encriptada. Te recomendaría que evites el uso de `ñ` y acentos para nombres de tablas, columnas, variables... si no tienes la codificación bien configurada esos caracteres podrían hacer que el código falle.

Intenta esto, he puesto algunos comentarios. El código te dirá lo que ocurre porque se controlan todos los posibles errores.

Cualquier cosa lo dices en comentario.

```
<?php
  

/*
    ¿Termina con R mayúscula? ¿En serio?
*/
if(isset($_POST["enviarR"])){


    $email=  !empty($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : NULL;
    $nombre= !empty($_POST["nombre"]) ? $_POST["nombre"] : NULL;
    $apellidos= !empty($_POST["apellidos"]) ? $_POST["apellidos"] : NULL;
    /*Evitemos ñ*/
    $password = !empty($_POST["contraseña"]) ? $_POST["contraseña"] : NULL;
    $fecha=  !empty($_POST["fecha"]) ? $_POST["fecha"] : NULL;
    $pais=!empty($_POST["pais"]) ? $_POST["pais"] : NULL;
    if( $email && $nombre && $apellidos  && $password && $fecha && $pais) {
        /*
            El include aquí, 
            cada cosa en su momento
        */
        include_once "../Database/database.php";
        $conexion = new Base_datos();       
        $sql="INSERT INTO registro_usuario (Email,Nombre,Apellido,Password,Fecha,País) VALUES (:email,:nombre,:apellidos,:password,:fecha,:pais)";
        $cifra_contra = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        if ($valor= $conexion->Conectar()->prepare($sql)) {
            if($valor->execute([':email'=>$email, ':nombre'=>$nombre, ':apellidos'=>$apellidos, ':password'=>$cifra_contra, ':fecha'=>$fecha,':pais'=>$pais])){
                $msg=sprintf("Fila(s) insertada(s) %d",$conexion->rowCount());
            } else {
                $msg=sprintf("Error SQL: %s",$conectar->errorInfo()[2]);                    
            }
        } else {
            $msg=sprintf("Error preparando la consulta: %s",$conectar->errorInfo()[2]);
        }
    } else {
        $msg="Datos del POST vacíos";
    }
    echo $msg;

} else {

?>

<style>

  .alerta{

      display:inline;

          }       
</style>

<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: Amigo quisiera saber como se llama ese estilo de formato que utilizaste para las variables  $email=  !empty($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : NULL; Tiene algún nombre en especial ese estilos de variables y para que sirve sirve el signo ?

Answer (score 0):

Era una estupidez realmente pero me di cueta gracias a la respuesta de A.Cedano

$msg=sprintf("Error SQL: %s",$valor->errorInfo()[2]);
echo $msg;

Con esta line me imprimió que mi base de datos no estaba seleccionada jamás pensé que fuera eso

**Antes**

$sqlConetion="mysql:host=".$this->servidor ;";dbname=".$this->base_datos;

**Despues**
$sqlConetion="mysql:host=".$this->servidor. ";dbname=".$this->base_datos;

Solo era una posición de un punto y coma y agregar un punto de mas y ya..

Aprte de so era eliminar las comillas como dijo A.Cedano